# The method addAll(Collection<? extends Set<Integer>>) is not applicable for the arguments (Set<Integer>)

Tags: java, generics, set

I've been away from Java for over a decade, and generics were something I'd just barely encountered before I set it aside. I'm coming back and working on a practice problem, I'm running into an error I can't make sense of.

The minimal example:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> powerSet = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
Set<Integer> nthSizeSubset = new HashSet<Integer>();
powerSet.addAll(nthSizeSubset);
```

Yields the error in Eclipse:

> The method addAll(Collection<? extends Set>) in the type Set<Set> is not applicable for the arguments (Set)

I'm not precisely sure if a type can be said to extend itself, but either way, I'm not sure how to make sense of the error and fix it.

Comment: Just `.add(nthSizeSubset)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addAll` is used when you want to add a `Collection` of your parameterized type. But your parameterized type is `Set<Integer>`. Therefore, trying to `addAll` a `Set<Integer>` to a `Set<Set<Integer>>` doesn't work because it is expecting something like `Collection<Set<Integer>>`. But you gave it only `Set<Integer>`. Therefore, invalid parameter.

The guiding light with generics is your type parameter. It decides the relationships between data, methods, and the classes that house both. Whenever you read the Javadocs, always think about it with respect to the type parameter.